# Double Integral for Gaussian Quadrature

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, quadrature

I am trying to apply the Gaussian-Legendre Quadrature rule to a Double Integral, namely

$$
\int^1_0 \int^1_0 \text{sin}(x^2+y^2)dxdy
$$

I have done the following:

Define $\phi_n(x)$ is the Legendre polynomial of degree $n$. Using the fact that 
\begin{align*}
\int^b_{a} f(x)dx &= \frac{b-a}{2}\int^1_{-1}f\left(\frac{b-a}{2}x+\frac{a+b}{2}  \right)dx\\ &= \frac{b-a}{2}\sum^{n}_{i=1}w_if\left(\frac{b-a}{2}x_i+\frac{a+b}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

with

$$
w_i = \frac{2}{(1-x_i^2)[\phi_n '(x_i)]^2}
$$

where each $x_i$ is a root of the polynomial $\phi_n(x)$, I have applied this logic to the double integral case and obtained

$$
\int^1_0\int^1_0 F(x,y)dxdy = \frac{1}{4}\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}w_i w_jF\left(\frac{1}{2}x_i+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}y_i+\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$

with

$$
w_i = \frac{2}{(1-x_i^2)[\phi_n '(x_i)]^2} \ \ \text{  and  } \ \ w_j = \frac{2}{(1-y_j^2)[\phi_n '(y_j)]^2}
$$

However, this logic has not worked under implementation (using C++ code).

Is the logic here sound? Or have I oversimplied the issue?

Your help will be appreciated.

Note, I looked throughly online and on this website for an and couldn't find anything conclusive - if there is a link, I would appreciate it if you could direct me over.

Comment: Of course there's no need to do this one as a double integral, if you use the expansion $\sin(x^2+y^2) = \sin(x^2)\cos(y^2)+\cos(x^2)\sin(y^2)$.

Comment: Oh yes, I am aware - however the assignment specifically requested that we make use of double integrals. Thank you though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what way has it "not worked"?

Have you checked your quadrature method on $1$-variable integrals?  How does it do on
$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sin(x^2)\; dx\; dy$ and $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \cos(y^2)\; dx\; dy$?

Comment: The approximation does not seem to be converging to $\frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}}$ as required, it seems to rather converge (slowly) to $0$ as $n$ increases. Following your advice, I evaluated both double integrals that you posted and they don't seem giving the correct approximation.

Comment: And it seems to work fine with one-variable integrals - it's just double integrals that seem to have an issue

Comment: Seems like some problem with your programming then.  BTW, the answer should not be $1/(6 \sqrt{2})$, it should be $ \pi FresnelS(\sqrt{2/\pi}) FresnelC(\sqrt{2/\pi})$
or approximately $0.5612903983$.

Comment: I have noticed that, as you said, my code was the issue: I seemed to be summing all the diagonal entries instead of *all* the entries - I have applied the logic above and I now get the right answer.